# Can't remove item from List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to remove item from products in DeleteProduct method and Remove method returns true but all items still in list and I can't figure out why.

As I understend products list creates at the first start of the application and at static constructor it fills with items. Then in DeleteProduct method one of the items removes and executes Products Method.

Please someone explane it!

```
public class ProductController
    : Controller
{
    private static IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> products = null;

    static ProductController()
    {
        products = new List<ProductViewModel>
        {
            new ProductViewModel{Id = 0, Description = "Milk", Price = 21.0, IsAvailable = true, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now},
            new ProductViewModel{Id = 1, Description = "Bread", Price = 10.10, IsAvailable = false, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now},
            new ProductViewModel{Id = 2, Description = "Soure creame", Price = 34.5, IsAvailable = true, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now},
            new ProductViewModel{Id = 3, Description = "Chocolate", Price = 31.0, IsAvailable = true, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now},
            new ProductViewModel{Id = 4, Description = "Apples", Price = 1.0, IsAvailable = true, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now},
        };
    }
    public ActionResult Products()
    {
        return View(products);
    }

    public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

        if (product != null)
            products.ToList().Remove(product);

        return RedirectToAction("Products");
    }
}
```

Comment: What you doing is terrible practice (do not use `static` variables), but it would work if you first tested if `products` is `null`, and only then assign the list to it.

Comment: [ASP.NET MVC How safe are static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225113/asp-net-mvc-how-safe-are-static-variables)

Comment: Suggest you also read [ASP.NET MVC controllers static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126957/asp-net-mvc-controllers-static-methods)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I definitely will not store data in static variables and also use static variables. Just wanted to create test example

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in that line:

```
products.ToList().Remove(product);
```

By calling `ToList()` you generate a new list and remove the product from the newly created list. In order to make the code work, change the products field to type `List`:

```
private static List<ProductViewModel> products = null;
```

This way, you can use the methods of a list and do not have to cast or use `ToList()`. You can call `Remove` directly on the products field:

```
products.Remove(product);
```

Comment: @mjwills thanks for the hint. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that ToList generates new list

Answer (score 1):

When you do `products.ToList()` you are creating a new list. So, when you do `products.ToList().Remove(product)`, you are removing the product from this new list.

You could do something like:

```
if (product != null)
{
    List<ProductViewModel> productList = products.ToList();
    productList.Remove(product);
    products = productList;
}
```

Or, you could change so the static variable `products` is of type `List<ProductViewModel>`, so you wouldn't have to create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing:

```
var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

if (product != null)
    products.ToList().Remove(product);
```

with:

```
products.Remove(product);
```

and replacing:

```
private static IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> products = null;
```

with:

```
private static List<ProductViewModel> products = null;
```

The `ToList` is unnecessary since it creates a **new** `List` and them removes the `product` from that **new** `List` (which is basically pointless).

The `FirstOrDefault` is unnecessary since `Remove` will take care of the *only remove this item if it is already there* problem for you. *The code as is basically checks **twice** whether the item is there before removing it.*

The `IEnumerable` has no benefits over leaving it as its 'raw' type (`List`), and using `IEnumerable` removes the ability to call `Remove`.

**Also consider using `ConcurrentBag` rather than `List` - for [thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950955/concurrentbagmytype-vs-listmytype).**